# finding rgb value of cut point of diagonal of rectangle in objective-c 

Tags: objective-c

I have to find the RGB of point where two diagonals of a rectangle cut each other in objective-c.

more explanation of my requirements:

lets take a rectangular image draw two diagonal from the corner like we make cross. I need the RGB value of the cut point.

Regards

Satya

Comment: Are you asking for a way to calculate the center point of a rectangle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it on the Mac.  With focus locked on the graphics context in question:

```
NSRect aRect;
NSPoint centerOfRect = NSMakePoint(NSMidX(aRect), NSMidY(aRect));
NSColor *aColor = NSReadPixel(centerOfRect);
```

If you're working on the iPhone, then you'll want to find the equivalent macros for CGRect instead of NSRect, and the related CG Function.